# How to append the output of a servlet using JQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am currently making a website. Basically when the user scrolls to the bottom of the screen I am going to download another 10 posts (I'm making a little social network). To do this I have downloaded JQuery. The following JavaScript is ran when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page:

```
page++;
var next = 'posts?page=' + page;
$('.pContainer').append("code that loads the servlet in the next var goes here");
```

Inside the posts servlet I have a few out.println statements to test this. I have tried using JSP: Include tags inside the append brackets but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use an ajax call?

```
page++;
var next = 'posts?page=' + page;
$.get(next, function (data) {
    $('.pContainer').append(data);
});
```

This requests a page and appends the data returned from the page.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1):

You should use a plugin; just search for 'jQuery lazy load'.

You can always build your own, but it's not worth the hassle.  I think the concept behind it is to calculate the position of a bottom element, say #bottom-bar, and if it is above a certain threshold, say less than 200px below the bottom of the page, you would load elements on top of it until it is pushed down further.

Scrolling would be the trigger that makes it load more items.

**additional details:** (not tested)

```
$(window).scroll(function (){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + 500 > $('#bottom-bar').offsest().top) {
        var newcontent = $('<div class="content"></div>');
        newcontent.load('http://source.of.data.com', function(data) {
            $('#bottom-bar').before(newcontent);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'm not quite sure how it would work with what I want to do though. I want to add content from a database to the page as the user scrolls, not just wait until they scroll to the bottom of the page to load static content.

Comment: Yep, that's how lazy loading features work.  It actually doesn't load as the user scrolls, it load as the user approaches the end of the page.  If you only load as the user scrolls, then what would happen if the user goes to the top of the page and scrolls down again?  The position of an element is used to determine where the end of the content is, and then load new content.  Loading new content would be simple; check out the updated post.